# Sql Server Reporting Services 2005 report import from PDF

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, import

Is there a tool or programming method available to take the layout defined in a PDF and import it into Sql Server Reporting Services 2005?

Quite a few layouts are created as PDFs by third parties. It would make development a lot easier if I could use some of the layout already defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know of anything that will do this.

The only way I could think of is to convert the PDF file into a RDLC file.  The RDLC file is a XML file, and follows a specific schema.  To do this, would take a lot of time.  Your probably better of creating the reports in report services manually.

I will definitely keep an eye out on this thread, however, I am quite certain that this solution does not yet exist.

Comment: I would like to fulfill a similar requirement as the one asked in the original question. Do you know if anything exists now, 9 years later, to do this? (Using SQL Server Data Tools 2015)

Comment: I have since moved away from my role as a Reporting Services guru.  I am now out of the loop, and I do not know.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Jon's answer concerning turning the PDF into XML and using that as a base sounds like a possible solution, but as he said the time and effort behind it probably wouldn't make it worth it at all.

As far as I know, I don't recall any sort of true layout-importing feature to SSRS, nor have I heard of any third party tools which would make it easier. If I had, I would have already purchased it, because a major sink of my own time is replicating forms and reports generated on a client's legacy system to work on SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have the same problem, but if I have to, I will take the pdf and save them as images -- allowing me to insert them into the report -- as a last resort.